# graph plotting api ( supporting editing/clipping at runtime) in java

Tags: java, netbeans, desktop-application, rcp, netbeans-platform

Need suggestions regarding Graph plotting java api which supports editing at runtime for netbeans platform application. Need to know about the possibility of making changes via mouse clicks and drags in the generated graph.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JChart2D](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/): [ZoomableChart](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc/info/monitorenter/gui/chart/ZoomableChart.html), could be the thing you need.

I used that a while ago.

*hth*